# How can I remove "Get the mobile App" button from SharePoint on-premise 2019 site?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, modern-experience, 2019

How can I remove "Get the mobile App" button from SharePoint on-premise 2019 site?

I know the PowerShell to remove it from SP Online. But, it is not working in SharePoint 2019 on-premise.

PowerShell working in SPO : `Set-SPOTenant -UserVoiceForFeedbackEnabled $false`

Also, I can add an application customizer for the same, but I'm finding an alternative way to this problem.

Is there any PowerShell available for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no powershell available to hide the "Get the mobile App" button in SharePoint server 2019.

You need to use custom CSS to hide the button using SPFX webpart.

Reference:

https://n8d.at/remove-feedback-buttons-from-sharepoint-footer-through-application-customizer/